# Match valid IP by grep and regular expression

Tags: regex, linux, bash, grep

Please advice what wrong in my syntax , and why the following regular expression doesn’t work

this example was tested under bash shell:

```
echo 12.212.12.198 | grep "^(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]| [1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$"
```

- Not get any output

The same about all IP’s as 192.9.200.12 , 172.18.12.34 , etc …

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `-E` (PATTERN is an extended regular expression (ERE))
Here is one good working found on `google`:

```
grep -E "^([1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.([1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.([1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.([1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$"
```

---

This as four part of `([1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])` that work like this

```
[1-9]           # 1-9
[1-9][0-9]      # 10-99
1[0-9][0-9]     # 100-199
2[0-4][0-9]     # 200-249
25[0-5]         # 250-255
```

Leading `0` is not valid, so this does not give valid if there is leading `0`

Comment: about your first example its also match not valid IP's as  2212.212.12.198

Comment: @maihabunash You are correct, fixed.

Comment: One point for a possible improvement: IPs with leading zeros are invalid.

Comment: @Cyrus You are correct.  Updated my post